# Cannot subscript a value of type [NSURL]

Tags: swift, nsurl

I am getting the following error. Is there a way around this?

i want to read text file from URL

```
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxx.com/file.txt")!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

struct FactBook {
    let factsArray = [requestURL]

    //let factsArray = ["my text"]  ---> is working

    func randomFact() -> String {
        let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(factsArray.count)))

        //Error here...
        return factsArray[randomInt]  
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: You create a request but do you ever load the file?

Comment: In order to get the *content* of the remote text file, you have to *execute* the download somewhere...

Comment: let `factsArray = [NSURL]()`  , to create an array that will hold NSURL's and then you must append the URL's to the array... `factsArray.append(newFactNSURL)`

Answer (score 1):

`randomFact` is declared to return a String, `factsArray` is an `[NSURL]`, hence indexing it is an `NSURL`.  Change the function type to:

```
func randomFact() -> NSURL {
```

and you should be good to go

Further observations:

- You're not ever loading the contents of the URL, so it's not clear that even this change really solves your problem.
- As it stands, there's only one element of `factsArray` so randomizing it seems pointless.
- It seems likely you're really wanting to strings from the URL and then return a random element of the returned strings.